# How to display multiple error messages for different input fields with $_session?

Tags: php, validation, session

I'm trying create a sign up page that contains multiple input fields. What I'm having difficulty is displaying an error message for each fields. The register function is in a file of its own. Now I've followed several other solutions but somehow it didn't work. I'm pretty sure this a noob question. This what my current code looks like:

register_func.php

```
<?php
   session_start();
   require 'config/database.php';

   // get register form data if form submit

   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $fname = filter_var($_POST['fname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
      $lname = filter_var($_POST['lname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
      $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
      $username = filter_var($_POST['username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
      $password = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
      $confirm_passwd = filter_var($_POST['conf_passwd'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
      $avatar = $_FILES['avatar'];

      $errors = [];
      // Validate input values
      if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($email) || empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($confirm_passwd) || empty($avatar)) {
        $errors['fname'] = "This field is required!";
        $errors['lname'] = "This field is required!";
        $errors['email'] = "This field is required!";
        $errors['username'] = "This field is required!";
        $errors['password'] = "This field is required!";
        $errors['conf_passwd'] = "This field is required!";
        $errors['avatar'] = "Please upload a file!";
      }

      // Other validation messages will be added once one error message gets display

      if (count($errors) > 0) {
         $_SESSION['signup-data'] = $_POST;
         $_SESSION['errors'] = $errors;
         header('Location: ' . ROOT_URL . 'signup.php');
         exit();
      }
 } else {
     // if button not submit, bounce back to signup page
     header('Location: ' . ROOT_URL . 'signup.php');
     exit();
 }
```

signup.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 require 'config/constants.php';

 // produce errors
 $fname_errors = $_SESSION['errors']['fname'] ?? null;

 // get data back to input box if there is error
 $firstname = $_SESSION['signup-data']['fname'] ?? null;

 // delete error and signup data session if there is no problem
 unset($_SESSION['signup-data']);
 unset($_SESSION['errors']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dynamic PHP Blog with MySQL and Admin Panel</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?= ROOT_URL; ?>css/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <section class="form_section">
    <div class="container form_section-container">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <form automcomplete="off" action="<?= ROOT_URL; ?>register_func.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['fname'])) echo 'hasError';?>" value="<?= $firstname; ?>">
            <?php if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['fname'])) : ?>
                <p><?= $_SESSION['errors']['fname']?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" class="" value="">
            
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="" value="">
            
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="" value="">
        
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="" value="">
            
            <input type="password" name="conf_passwd" id="conf_passw" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="" value="">
            
            <div class="form_control">
                <label for="avatar">Use Avatar</label>
                <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">
            </div>
            
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn">Sign Up</button>
            <small>Already have an account? <a href="signin.php">Login</a></small>
        </form>
    </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
[image: Validation error]

Answer (score 0):

Hello **@Ismail9403** you can use this logic in your code

For all validation messages on top, you can use this code
https://www.screencast.com/t/0ASorTsm

```
<?php 

if(isset($_SESSION['errors']) && !empty($_SESSION['errors']))
{
  foreach($_SESSION['errors'] as $error)
  {
    ?>
    "<p><?= $error ?></p>"
    <?php 
  }
}
?>
  
  <?php 
}
?>
```

For individual form fields

```
<form automcomplete="off" action="<?= ROOT_URL; ?>register_func.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['errors']['fname'])) echo 'hasError';?>" value="<?= $firstname; ?>">

                <p><?= $_SESSION['errors']['fname'] ?? ''?></p>

            <input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" class="" value="">

            <p><?= $_SESSION['errors']['lname'] ?? ''?></p>
            
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" class="" value="">

            <p><?= $_SESSION['errors']['email'] ?? ''?></p>
            
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="" value="">

            <p><?= $_SESSION['errors']['username'] ?? ''?></p>
        
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="" value="">
            <p><?= $_SESSION['errors']['password'] ?? ''?></p>
            
            <input type="password" name="conf_passwd" id="conf_passw" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="" value="">
            <p><?= $_SESSION['errors']['conf_passwd'] ?? ''?></p>
            
            <div class="form_control">
                <label for="avatar">Use Avatar</label>
                <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatar">
            </div>
```

Comment: Where do I put this code?

Comment: You can check the answer You can use the `Null coalescing operator` for individual field
`$_SESSION['errors']['fname'] ?? ''`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php

Comment: I forgot to say. I want to display for each input box. I just edited my question with an example image which I forgot to upload.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work